# Getting Server 2008 R2 to ignore all traffic from Internet-facing NIC, leaving it to a VM

Tags: linux, networking, security, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization

I got in to Server 2008 R2 via Dreamspark and would like to start learning on it.

I don't have much option but to put it on a system sitting between the Internet and my home LAN due to electricity bills and the fact that 3 computers in an 11x11 space in 102 degree weather is pretty stygian.

Currently I use a ClearOS gateway to manage everything, what I'd like to do is take my server 2008 R2 box, which has two NICs, and drop it at the head of my network. I'd want Server 2008 R2 to ignore all traffic on the external facing NIC and pass it to a virtual ClearOS gateway, and to put all its Internet traffic through its other NIC - which will face the rest of my network and be the default gateway for it.

The theory is to keep the potentially vulnerable Server 2008 R2 install as tucked behind a Linux box as possible, without sacrificing too much performance. This is a home network that occasionally hosts dedicated game servers and voice chat servers, so most malicious activity is in the form of drive by non-targeted attacks, however, I don't trust Windows Server because I don't know the OS well enough, yet.

So, three questions: How do I do this, am I going to be reasonably more secure doing this than if I just let the Server 2008 R2 rig handle all the network traffic and DHCP (not an option), and should I virtualize the Server 2008 R2 rig instead and if so in what? (Core 2 Duo e6600 w/ 5 gigs usable RAM)

Comment: Are you sure you're required to put it on the internet and not a internet accessible LAN?  Why can't you put it on a switch right behind the ClearOS gateway?  The only reason to set it up as you suggest is for dual homing.  The answer to your question is to install VMWare ESXi on the server.  Configure the management to be on the second internal NIC.  Configure both interfaces to be separate virtual switches.  Install W2k8 server in a VM and route it however you feel comfortable for your project.

Comment: whats with the -ive votes?

Comment: This cannot be put on a switch behind the clearOS gateway because I cannot have that many physical systems on in a home environment.

My total power draw is enough that with three systems on if, for some reason, all end up on a heavy load while I have my speakers and monitors on, I'll throw the breakers.

Comment: @Aceth: It attracted negative votes because questions about home computer and home network setups are off-topic here (see the FAQ). The question should have been asked on SuperUser.

Comment: @Starfish - It's still a server related issue, which is what I thought this site was about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already set this sort of thing in similar places! I'm glad someone else thinks like me! :D

Nope you can keep the server 2008 R2 as is! then ...
on the NIC thats internet facing .. in the properties disable all the protocols apart from the VM bridging (hyperv / vmware / virtualbox) then in the virtual machine bridge the NIC to that internet facing NIC.. job done the server 2008 R2 will now ignore everything coming in / out on that interface :)

Comment: Awesome, this answers my question and then some. I didn't realize the various VM tools used their own protocols to interact with hardware NICs.